# C++ Checking if a double is within .1 of another double (+/-)

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, compare

I'm running a bit of code where I need to compare two 2D arrays for any variance. I've tried using the following line of code to check and compare the values, but the test fails every time = `if(arr1[a][b] != arr2[a][b] || arr1[a][b] + .1 != arr2[a][b] || arr1[a][b] - .1 != arr2[a][b]) {`.

I know this is failing because of the `||` statement, because one of the requirements is met. So I've got to find another way to determine if the double stored in a specific location in the array matches the other array in the parallel location.

Here's my full code:

```
int numberOfFailedCompares = 0;
for(int a = 0; a < 20; a++) {
    int b = 0;
    while(b < 20) {

        if(arr1[a][b] != arr2[a][b] || arr1[a][b] + .1 != arr2[a][b] || arr1[a][b] - .1 != arr2[a][b]) {
            numberOfFailedCompares++;
            cout << numberOfFailedCompares << endl;
        }

        b++;
    }
}
```

Is there a statement in C++ which will allow me to check if the value is within the +/- .1 threshold? Something like

```
if(arrLocation1 (+/- .1) == arrLocation1) {
... 
}
```

Comment: Does "fails every time" mean it's never true when it should be, or it's always true when it shouldn't be, or what?

Comment: Also, is 1.0 supposed to match 1.05? Because those are closer than 0.1 apart, but they're not exactly 0.1 apart, and you're testing for exactly 0.1 apart.

Comment: Also, what if the numbers are 0.999999999999999 apart or 1.000000000000001 apart?

Comment: You're right, I've found a way to have this work, using nested if statements, but the explicit nature of my current if statement is a fault. I'm going to be using the suggested less/greater than answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Variance" means "within X", and not "equal to something plus X or something minus X". Instead of comparing for equality, you compare for less/greater than your variance. So, for example, to test for variance of +/- .1:

```
if (b >= a-.1 && b <= a+.1)
```

Comment: I had to use the `||` instead of `&&`, simply because a single value cannot be greater and less than another value ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
#define eps .1
...
if( fabs(x-y) <= eps ) 
   ...
```